# Sorting string enum in Typescript and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, enums, typescript

I have a enum defined in Typescript:

```
enum PriorityLevel {
High = <any>'High',
Normal = <any>'Normal',
Low = <any>'Low'}
```

Then in my html I have:

```
<button id= "assignmentBtn" type="button" ng-repeat="item in list.getItems()" class="btn" ng-class="list.getcolor(item)">
        {{item.description}}
</button>
```

Where each item has a PriorityLevel.

My question is that I want to sort this list by PriorityLevel, so that High is on top, then Normal and then Low. 
I tried to add

```
ng-repeat="item in list.getItems() | orderBy:'priority'"
```

But obviously, this orders the items alpabetically.

I quess I have to make a custom orderby function, but can anyone help me with how that should look in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I quess I have to make a custom orderby function, but can anyone help me with how that should look in my case

Direct to a custom function in the controller:

```
ng-repeat="item in list.getItems() | orderBy:list.customOrder"
```

And `customOrder`:

```
customOrder = function(item) {
   return item.priority === 'High' ? 3
          : item.priority === 'Normal' ? 2 
          : 1
};
```